# React - How to not run function inside component children if user has no permission

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a react based app and I am checking user's permission before rendering some piece of jsx using a `HasRole` component. Everything works fine except if I have a function as a child of the HasRole component, the function is getting called every time the parent component renders, if the user doesn't have permission also. How do I prevent this from happening.

**HasRole.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class HasRole extends Component {
  render() {
    const { children, role, requiredRole } = this.props;
    if(!requiredRole.includes(role)) return null;
      return children;
    }
  }

  const getMapStateToProps = (extendWith = {}) => state => {
    return {
      role: state.auth.userType,
        ...extendWith
      }
  }

export default connect(getMapStateToProps)(HasRole);
```

And when I use the HasRole component to check permission, `{this.renderUsers}` is executed if user don't have permission also.

**MovieShow.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import HasRole from '../has-role';

class MovieShow extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  renderUsers(){
    ...
  }
  render(){
    return(

       ...
       <HasRole requireRole={["admin"]}>
           {this.renderUsers} // this will run if user is not admin also but the component wont be shown
       </HasRole>

  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Basically, as I understand it, you want to prevent HasRole to re-render after it has figured if the user has the proper role right ?

Comment: @MaieonBrix Thanks for looking into it. Actually, I don't want anything inside `<HasRole></HasRole>`  to run or render if the user don't have permission. Now it is rendered and passed as { children } to  HasRole. Basically, I have some `state` logic which is affected when the function is called and no user has permission.

Answer (score 1):

Make the rendersUsers a stateless functional component by dragging it out of the class instead.

https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

By doing this it should enable you to pass the requireRole param to it, and lock it behind permissions aswell.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer @p3rk

Comment: No problem @AneesMuhammed, hope you managed to figure it out. Was at work so had to type something quick.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that `renderUsers` is executed is because it is evaluated in Parent although rendered as children in HasRole. You could write your `HasRole` component to use used with `renderProps` like

```
class HasRole extends Component {
  render() {
    const { children, role, requiredRole } = this.props;
    if(!requiredRole.includes(role)) return null;
      return children();
    }
}
```

and then you would use it like

```
class MovieShow extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  renderUsers(){
    ...
  }
  render(){
    return(

       ...
       <HasRole requireRole={["admin"]}>
           {() => {return this.renderUsers()}}
       </HasRole>

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Shubham. This should work. But I actually have `HasRole` used in other places whose children are plane `jsx` and not functions. To make them work with the new pattern, I've tried changing them to something like `<HasRole requiredRole={["admin"]}>{() => (<div>...</div>)}</HasRole>. But it says `children is not a function`.

Comment: I created a demo, https://codesandbox.io/s/o78jw8k68q it works there. Can you check if there is an error elsewhere

Comment: It might be a case where you have multiple children to HasRole

Comment: As the error stated the children were not function in your case. Check this https://codesandbox.io/s/v30ym6z7ql

Comment: yes, that works, but `this.changeByAdminOnly()` is not called when wrapped inside the fn, though it is passing the permission check. For the same reason I've created this test `changeByAdminOnly` fn.

Comment: @AneesMuhammed, you would need some trigger to call that function, right? and shouldn't it be passed as props or something because calling a function from render that sets state will cause your application to go in a loop

Comment: Okay, Thanks. Setting state I added just for reference. what if it is a function doing something else with some constraints to prevent the loop, which should be executed only if the HasRole passes?

Comment: In that case just write `{this.changeByAdminOnly()}` if its nested inside a children function or else `{() => {this.changeByAdminOnly()}}`

Comment: Let me know if you still need help regarding this